# Curl: failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

When I am using this Curl command in my terminal:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/api/v1/quote/car-insurance --data '{"car_value": 20000.0, "driver_birthdate": "15/10/1990"}'`

I get this error message in my terminal:

```
Curl: failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Can someone explain me why the connection is being refused?

---

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const insuranceQuoteRoutes = require("./routes/insuranceQuotes")

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use("/api", insuranceQuoteRoutes)

app.listen(8080)

module.exports = app
```

---

**insuranceQuotes.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const {body, validationResult} = require("express-validator");

const insuranceQuoteController = require("../controllers/insuranceQuotesControllers")

const router = express.Router()

//carDateRegex: https://www.regextester.com/99555
const carDateRegex = /^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}$/

//Express-validator: https://express-validator.github.io/docs/
router.post("/v1/quote/car-insurance", [
    body("car_value").isFloat(),
    body("driver_birthdate").matches(carDateRegex)
], insuranceQuoteController.postInsuranceQuotes);

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Can you go to `localhost:8080/api/v1/quote/car-insurance` via browser?

Comment: as in type localhost:8080/api/v1/quote/car-insurance in my brower? no I get: This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @CoderCharmander: could you please let me know your thought process?

Comment: I succeeded running the program locally (without insuranceQuoteController). Check the console for errors.

Comment: how can I check the console if I can't open browser?

Comment: How do you run your app? (I don't have Skype, sorry.) Most likely it prints an error message to the console where you invoked npm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218149/discussion-between-codercharmander-and-charlinhovdb1).